# Steam not running proton games on separate EXT4 partition

Tags: permissions, wine, steam, ownership

I have a multi user system and if possible I'd like to prevent downloading every game 3 times.
Because of that I made a separate ext4 partition for my steam games and selected the partition in steam

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root   4096 May 21 17:06 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 root steam 16384 May  4 19:59 lost+found
drwxrwxr-x 3 root steam  4096 May 21 17:22 SteamLibrary
```

All proton games don't launch
I used the launch option PROTON_LOG=1 and the log said this

```
wineserver: /mnt/steam/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/1118200/pfx is not owned by you
wine: '/mnt/steam/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/1118200/pfx' is not owned by you
```

I know that this is solvable with a

```
chown -R user:user /mnt/steam
```

but I don't understand why I need to own the file
my group has every permission

I can't find anything online because there is a similar issue with having a ntfs partition that's filling my search results.

also my user is in the steam group.

ChatGPT mentioned something about acl and advanced permissions but this

```
sudo setfacl -R -d -m group:sharedgroup:rwx /mnt/steam/SteamLibrary
```

It seems that it would only set read/execute/write permissions, which I already have.

I wanted to ask if it is possible to fake own a mountpoint to multiple users or find some other workaround for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why I need to own the file my group has every permission

There may not be any technical reason for this check but a program is free in which conditions it checks.

These checks are probably done during the start-up of `wine` so you could create

- a wrapper script
- a `sudo` rule

so that the wrapper script would change the owner of these files to the caller:

```
# start-my-game.sh

file_paths=( '/mnt/steam/SteamLibrary/steamapps/compatdata/1118200/pfx' )

sudo chown "$USER" "${file_paths[@]}"

# or for simpler sudoers rules (allow each file separately)
for file in "${file_paths[@]}"; do
    sudo chown "$USER" "$file"
done

the usual start command line
```